# Implication of Lipschitz property

Tags: real-analysis, lipschitz-functions

I have to prove that, given $L=L(g, [a, b])$ the Lipschitz constant of $g:[a, b]\subset\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$, we have that if 
$$
\frac{|g(b)-g(a)|}{|b-a|}=L,\quad (\star)
$$
then $g(a+t(b-a))=g(a)+t(g(b)-g(a))$ for $0\leq t\leq1$.

**My attempt.** By setting $x=a+t(b-a)$ and $y=g(a)+t(g(b)-g(a))$, we have to prove that $g(x)=y$. I'm trying to show this using the inequalities
$$
|g(x)-g(a)|<L(x-a),\qquad |g(b)-g(x)|<L(b-x)
$$
(do these inequality come from the hypothesis $(\star)$?). In particular, undoing the absolute value of the first inequality we get
$$
g(a)+\frac{|g(b)-g(a)|}{|b-a|}(a-x)<g(x)<g(a)+\frac{|g(b)-g(a)|}{|b-a|}(x-a)=
$$
$$
=g(a)+\frac{|g(b)-g(a)|}{|b-a|}t(b-a)
$$
But how can I conclude that $g(x)=y$?

Thank You

Comment: If you are willing to assume that g is continuously differentiable there is a simple proof. $\frac 1 {b-a} |\int_a^{b} g'(x)dx|=L$ and this implies that $|g'|=1$. By continuity $g'=L$ or $g'=-L$ at all points. The form of g is clear from this. Actually, the general case can be handled using absolute continuity of g.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All points $(x,g(x))$ in the graph of $g$ lie in the region cut out by the inequalities
$$ a\le x\le b$$
$$-L \le \frac{ g(x)-g(a)}{x-a} \le L, \text{ if } a<x.$$
Also, all points in the graph lie in the region cut out by the inequalities
$$ a\le x\le b$$
$$-L \le \frac{ g(b)-g(x)}{b-x} \le L, \text{ if } x<b.$$
The intersection of the two regions is the line segment connecting $(a,g(a))$ and $(b,g(b))$.

Comment: Ok, I understand. But how can I formalize it analytically? Thank you

Comment: You posit an $(x,g(x))$ not on the line segment, say above it.  Then you see that that point is in one of the triangle-shaped regions but not the other, so that can't happen.  What about below the segment?  Same kind of reasoning, but now the other region is happy but the first one sad.  So that can't happen, either.  It might simplify things if you assume $g(a)<g(b)$, to start with.  (Note that if the result is true for $g$ it'salso  true for $-g$, so you are not losing generality by making this assumption.)